# Tell guest OS to use my dockerized mail server to send email

Tags: cron, email, postfix, docker, ssmtp

I have postfix running in a Docker container.
A cronjob try to send email, but reply

```
“(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)” error in the syslog
```

According to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog), the solution is to install postfix so CRON can send email.

I have postfix running on this Host, is there a way to use it ?
I have some other hosts and postfix isn't running on them, can I also tell them to use the distant docker mail server?

Comment: Without seeing the crontab, we can't guess which problem you ran into.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but what I see is that a process tried to send mail and it failed. I don't understand why the details of the command whose output got piped into `mail` would be important.

Comment: @ThomasDickey & G-Man : please read this http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it & http://askubuntu.com/questions/222512/cron-info-no-mta-installed-discarding-output-error-in-the-syslog , the crontab is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that postfix is not running but that it should be listening on a mapped port 25 or 587 on the host. Even if that is the case,  with not installing postfix on the host, there is probably no installed that sends the mail (gotten from stdin or commandline parameters) to the port.

You install  the client programs [sSMTP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSMTP) or [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) for that, but I have solved this within a small wrapper program for my crontab entries that I was using anyway. The wrapper only sends mail if the program (the "real" crontab etnry it called) exits with non-zero exit value or its output contains the string "error:". That reduces the span from my own systems i.e. no email if the program ran fine. The program uses the Python standard library `smtp` module to send the caught output.

The wrapper runs the program with `subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`, and sends the result on error using:

```
 smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host="", port=0)  # by default 'localhost' and 25
 smtp.connect()
 smtp.sendmail(
     from_email, to_email_list,
     email_header_and_body
 )
```

By setting the host and port I also use this to run jobs from other docker containers.

Comment: Not sure if I got it, why should I use a hook script ? Is there no way to configure an external SMTP server ?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "hook" script is. There is no way to configure "vixie" cron (found on most Linuxes nowadays) to use a specific server/port.

Comment: solution seems to just install ssmtp or msmtp